# Recursively looking up files in jsTestDriver

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit, js-test-driver

Has any one figured out a way around jsTestDriver's inability to recursively lookup files for testing from config. 
Its documented here: http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/issues/detail?id=6

Currently we are not able to give something like /root/module/** in jsTestDriver config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed now in [JsTestDriver-1.3.5](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/downloads/list), so now you can do something like:

```
load:
  - js/**/*.js
  - data/**/*.json
```

Cheers